# Executor Lost Failure (executor ID: 1): Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue to run spark jobs.

My flow is more or less like:

- client have defined rules (hundreds of them)
- client select rules to run and provides input data
- job takes data and execute each rule on that data

Rules are definned as python files, and system executes them by running:

```py
for rule in rules:
    result = importlib.import_module(module).handle(glue_context, dataframe, global_params, rule_params)
```

This is working fine when I'm running them in batch of 10-15.
When I'm executing them in bigger batches (25-50) I'm getting errors.
Data set is not huge - 70k rows, 200 columns

For this dataset Glue is configured to use max 15 DPUs and G.1X worker type

One of those errors:

Driver:

```java
22/10/10 11:03:27 ERROR GlueExceptionAnalysisListener: [Glue Exception Analysis] {"Event":"GlueExceptionAnalysisTaskFailed","Timestamp":1665399807544,"Failure Reason":"Executor Lost Failure (executor ID: 1): Some(Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.)","Stack Trace":[],"Task Launch Time":1665399760009,"Stage ID":49,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Executor ID":"1","Task ID":385}
```

And executor error:

```java
ShuffleMapStage 49 (fromRDD at DynamicFrame.scala:313) failed in 82.192 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 49.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 49.0 (TID 413) (10.10.1.184 executor 7): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2830)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:3331)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1783)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1844)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:484)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:484)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498
```

Or another one:

```java
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
ShuffleMapStage 116 (fromRDD at DynamicFrame.scala:313) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. 
Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: The relative remote executor(Id: 7), which maintains the block data to fetch is dead. at
 org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:796) at
 org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:711) at
 org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:70) at
 org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29) at
 scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:480) at
 scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:486) at
 scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454) at
 org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31) at
 org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37) at
 scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454) at
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:225) at
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(SortExec.scala:132) at
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898) at
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898) at
 org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52) at
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373) at
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337) at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373) at
```

From performance point of view, I don't see any very stressed components:
[image]

One change i did is: `'--conf': 'spark.task.cpus=2'` this allows me to run a little bit more rules, but stil fails after some time.

Full error logs: https://mega.nz/file/9QshCAAL#c4U7TSBJlEhD6SSrnhMXp1Wp8P9CuYXV9P7il4WqUqo

Any clues/hints what should i check/modify ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at your error logs you see that you've got a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` at `java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3109)`. That seems to hint at the fact that the problem is related to your input data.

Are the objects that you're reading in deeply nested? This might make the default stack size (256kB - 1MB, depending on your JVM) not large enough.

I'm not really experienced with pyspark, but [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766150/change-default-stack-size-for-spark-driver-running-from-jupyter) shows how to do it in pyspark. Start out with 4MB and try increasing it slowly if needed. Possibly you'll need to increase it for your executors as well (just add a second config with `executor` instead of `driver` in there if needed)

Comment: @Koedit Thanks. My data is like excel table with operations like "if colum X > 20 than column Y = 40". Once a while I have operations on whole dataset: "if average of column X is > 20 than Y = 60". Thats all.

Now I'm very limited in my time to work on that issue. But will try all of Your sugestions.

As workaround, I'm dumping all of my data after 5 steps to s3 bucket, and then I'm reading them as new source. I'm not getting that errors any more, but i have to pay the price of pushing/pulling data from/to s3.