# java.lang.StackOverflowError when saving file parquet pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, parquet

I ran a glue job and it exist a error `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when saving file to parquet.
My dataframe has more then 400k rows and 250 columns.
Here is log:

```
  File "/tmp/glue-job.py", line 147, in transform_to_column_based_format
    .save(s3_output_folder_url)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1109, in save
    self._jwrite.save(path)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1659.save.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.rewrite$1(QueryPlan.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformUpWithNewOutput$1(QueryPlan.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.rewrite$1(QueryPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformUpWithNewOutput$1(QueryPlan.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.rewrite$1(QueryPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformUpWithNewOutput$1(QueryPlan.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.rewrite$1(QueryPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformUpWithNewOutput$1(QueryPlan.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.rewrite$1(QueryPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformUpWithNewOutput$1(QueryPlan.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.c
2022-12-16 13:37:28,789 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/glue-job.py", line 228, in <module> LeadDMSMirror().main() File "/tmp/glue-job.py", line 224, in main self.load_and_update_to_delta_table(table_name=self.historical_table_name, primary_key=self.current_table_name_pk, is_history_table=True) File "/tmp/glue-job.py", line 214, in load_and_update_to_delta_table self.transform_to_column_based_format(current_df, full_load_df, primary_key, s3_output_folder_url, is_full_load=True ) File "/tmp/glue-job.py", line 147, in transform_to_column_based_format .save(s3_output_folder_url) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1109, in save self._jwrite.save(path) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__ answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco return f(*a, **kw) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name), value) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1659.save. : java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.rewrite$1(QueryPlan.scala:188) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformUpWithNewOutput$1(QueryPlan.scala:193) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:387) at
```

I don't exactly what bug is and hope to find solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default stack size for spark driver running from jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766150/change-default-stack-size-for-spark-driver-running-from-jupyter)

Answer (score 4):

From the stack trace you see that Spark is having issues making your query plan. In a kind of loop way, this smells like recursion gone wrong, it is continuously calling functions in `Queryplan` -> `TreeNode` -> `QueryPlan` -> `TreeNode` -> ...

That's a classic problem that makes your stack overflow. As causes (and solutions) for these issues I think of the following:

- **Cause**: You have added some recursion to your code which is somehow going wrong.

  - **Solution**: Make sure you're not calling functions within loops/themselves and try to make your code as simple as possible
- **Cause**: Your data is deeply complex and nested, and somehow making a query plan for this is very complicated

  - **Solution**: Increase the JVM stack size on your driver. The default stack size (depending on your JVM) is 256kB - 1MB. Try out 4MB for example. An example of how to do it in Pyspark can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769985/15405732).

Comment: Can you have some checkpoints at line nos 228, 224, 214, 147 to see whats happening.  Without the actual code, data sample its difficult to give any solutions.  Also whats the glue configuration, the number of DPUs, is it STANDARD, 1X or 2X?

Comment: I already put a checkpoint and it's ok. This error happens at the save stage. I also try 1X and 2X, 3DPU-10DPU